# Disk method to find volume of solid revolved around x axis

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

Use the disk method to find the volume of the solid generated when the region bounded by $\displaystyle y=\frac1{(1-100x^2)^\frac14}$, $y=0$, $x=0$, and $\displaystyle x=\frac1{20}$ is revolved around the x-axis

Answer (score 1):

We get immediately that the volume is equal to 
$$\int_0^{1/20} \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{1-100x^2}}\,dx.$$
For the integration, I suggest making the change of variable $10x=u$. Then $dx=\frac{1}{10}\,du$. We end up needing the integral
$$\int_{u=0}^{1/2} \frac{\pi}{10\sqrt{1-u^2}}\,du.$$

Note that $\int \frac{du}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}=\arcsin u +C$.

Comment: this makes sense, however the denominator is to the fourth root not to the square root so thats where im having trouble

Comment: Please remember that for $y=f(x)$ the volume is $\int_a^b\pi (f(x))^2\,dx$. So I squared the fourth root and got a square root. Recall that $(w^{1/4})^2=w^{1/2}$.

Comment: okay i see. i got the final answer to be (pi^2)/6 but that is incorrect

Comment: @LeahLewy: Apologies, I misread the function. Have written down the correct function, the answer will turn out to be $\frac{\pi^2}{60}$.